# Is there a way to use VarVector to represent raw data in Ml.net K-means clustering

Tags: c#, ml.net

I would like to use ML.Net K-means clustering on some 'raw' vectors which I've generated in-memory by processing another dataset. I would like to be able to select the length of the vectors at runtime.  All vectors within a given model will be the same length but that length may vary from model to model as I try out different clustering approaches.

I use the following code:

```
public class MyVector
{
   [VectorType]
   public float[] Values;
}

void Train()
{

    var vectorSize = GetVectorSizeFromUser();

    var vectors = .... process dataset to create an array of MyVectors, each with 'vectorSize' values

    var mlContext = new MLContext();

    string featuresColumnName = "Features";
    var pipeline = mlContext
        .Transforms
        .Concatenate(featuresColumnName, nameof(MyVector.Values))
        .Append(mlContext.Clustering.Trainers.KMeans(featuresColumnName, numberOfClusters: 3));

    var trainingData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(vectors);

    Console.WriteLine("Training...");
    var model = pipeline.Fit(trainingData);
}
```

The problem is that when I try to to run the training, I get this exception...

> Schema mismatch for feature column 'Features': expected
>   Vector, got VarVector (Parameter 'inputSchema')

I can avoid this for any given value of `vectorSize` (say 20) by using `[VectorType(20)]`, but the key thing here is I would like not to rely on a specific compile-time value.  Is there a recipe to allow for dynamically sized data to be used for this kind of training?

I can imagine various nasty workarounds involving dynamically constructing dataviews with dummy columns but was hoping there would be a simpler approach.

Comment: Looking through the issues and found [this](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/164#issuecomment-492938790). Would that help with your case?

Comment: Thanks Jon - that does indeed look like the way to do it.  The trick is to modify the creation of training data like this....  var schemaDef = SchemaDefinition.Create(typeof(MyVector));                schemaDef[nameof(MyVector.Values)].ColumnType = new VectorDataViewType(NumberDataViewType.Single, vectorSize);
                var trainingData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(vectors
                    , schemaDef
                    );  schemaDef also needs to be passed when the PredictionEngine is created.  If you want to write this up as an answer I'm happy to mark it as such :-)

Comment: You got it to work so feel free to get credit for the answer :) Glad I could help, though.

Comment: Thanks - done :-)

Comment: Awesome! Way better than what I could do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Jon for finding the link to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/164#issuecomment-492938790) issue which contains the required information.  The trick is to override the SchemaDefinition at run-time....

```
public class MyVector
{
   //it's not required to specify the type here since we will override in our custom schema 
   public float[] Values;
}

void Train()
{

    var vectorSize = GetVectorSizeFromUser();

    var vectors = .... process dataset to create an array of MyVectors, each with 'vectorSize' values

    var mlContext = new MLContext();

    string featuresColumnName = "Features";
    var pipeline = mlContext
        .Transforms
        .Concatenate(featuresColumnName, nameof(MyVector.Values))
        .Append(mlContext.Clustering.Trainers.KMeans(featuresColumnName, numberOfClusters: 3));

    //create a custom schema-definition that overrides the type for the Values field...  
    var schemaDef = SchemaDefinition.Create(typeof(MyVector));
    schemaDef[nameof(MyVector.Values)].ColumnType 
                  = new VectorDataViewType(NumberDataViewType.Single, vectorSize);

    //use that schema definition when creating the training dataview  
    var trainingData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(vectors,schemaDef);

    Console.WriteLine("Training...");
    var model = pipeline.Fit(trainingData);

    //Note that the schema-definition must also be supplied when creating the prediction engine...

    var predictor = mlContext
                    .Model
                    .CreatePredictionEngine<MyVector,ClusterPrediction>(model, 
                                          inputSchemaDefinition: schemaDef);

    //now we can use the engine to predict which cluster a vector belongs to...
    var prediction = predictor.Predict(..some MyVector...);  
}
```